ambiguity in "zeitweise"
Both DWDS and WordReference dictionaries say that "zeitweise" can mean either "occasionally" and "for a while". Is one of those meanings more common that the other? For instance, would it be possible to understand what the following sentence mean without asking for clarification? Theoretically, it could mean "I go abroad occasionally" (defines frequency) or "I go abroad for a while" (defines duration).

Ich gehe zeitweise ins Ausland.


My impression is that none of the examples in either reference that is chosen to show the meaning "occasionally" is very clear-cut. Often, the fact that something happens occasionally precludes that it is a permanent thing, and therefore implies that whatever happens does so temporarily (if multiple times). As such, in most, if not all, of the examples provided, one could argue that "zeitweise" does mean "for a while", "temporary", "for a limited amount of time", or at least emphasize that aspect rather than focusing on the occasional reoccurrence of the event.

I always use it in the sense of "occasionally". I would express "for a while" by "für eine Zeit". I haven't heard so far anybody using "zeitweise" in this sense, but if your dictionary says that it's possible, we can believe it.

Zeitweise means it's an exception to the rule for a limited time. The exact meaning depends on the verb.

Ich gehe zeitweise ins Ausland.

Because gehen is dynamic (movement or state-change), this can't be a timeless statement. So this says I go abroad for a while until I return.

Ich arbeite zeitweise im Ausland.

This on the other hand may be a timeless statement. It can either say I work abroad for a while until I return or I work abroad occassionally with the latter being more likely.

What is a timeless statement? "zeitweise" is related to time, so I do not understand how a sentence with it could be timeless.

A timeless statement is one that is valid at all time. That's how zeitweise ends up describing an endless on-off blinking.

The more frequent use is "for a while" or "for a duration of varying length". The two meanings are basically the same. They look at
time as some stream of time that can be broken into chunks of variable length. In "Ich gehe zeitweise ins Ausland" it means either "I'll be in foreign countries for some time in the future" (grammar present tense but meaning future tense) or "I have a habit of living part time in other contries" (vacations etc) or "I am often on business trips outside the country" (which can hardly be predicted). In both cases "zeitweise" means statistical imprecision by the nature of the interludes or that the speaker wants to hide which days are considered (for example a phrase of a drug dealer in a film ...)

I understood the ambiguity of the word, but the two meanings are certainly not the same

They are the same in the sense of referring to fluctuations in the statistics of absence: one statistics indicating varying lengths, the other varying frequency.
